# Some definitions without full choice

Tags: lo.logic, axiom-of-choice

Assume DC($\aleph_1$).

Can we define the following:

1. Basis for a vector space $V$ over a field $K$ such that $\operatorname{card}(K) \leq \aleph_1$ and we happen to find a generating set of $V$ of cardinality $\leq \aleph_1$.
2. Linear dimension making the same assumption as above.
3. Transcendence degree of a field $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ if we happen to know that $K$ is of cardinality $\leq \aleph_1$.
   etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any appeal to the axiom of choice, if you have a vector space which is well-ordered then it has a basis. Moreover, if you have a generating set which is well-ordered then the vector space has a basis. The latter one allows you to have that the field itself is not necessarily well-ordered (as in your first point, where it is).

The same point applies to all three points. Once an object is well-ordered, we can use transfinite induction to do anything without any appeal to the axiom of choice.

(Do note, however, that in models like Solovay's model the cardinality of $\Bbb C$ is not $\aleph_1$, and it may or may not have a transcendence basis over $\Bbb Q$.)

Comment: Thank you. But what is the cardinality of $\mathbb{C}$ in Solovay's model then?

Comment: I read in Jech's axiom of choice that the generalized continuum hypothesis implies the axiom of choice. What for the continuum hypothesis itself?

Comment: In the Solovay model, the cardinality of $\Bbb C$ cannot be described by an ordinal. To see more about the continuum hypothesis itself, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404807/how-to-formulate-continuum-hypothesis-without-the-axiom-of-choice/

Comment: And the same thing for Shelah's model, right?

Comment: And also, is $\aleph_1$ the same thing as $\omega_1$ in these models?

Comment: $\aleph_1$ is by definition in $\sf ZF$ equals to $\omega_1$. In every model where $\Bbb C$ cannot be well-ordered, its cardinality is not an ordinal. That's all we can say.

Comment: "That is all we can say" might be a bit of an overstatement; we can make some comparisons between the continuum and well-ordered cardinals. For example, we can say (and you probably have said elsewhere) that $\mathbb C$ can be mapped onto $\omega_1$ (a theorem of ZF) and that in Solovay's model $\omega_1$ cannot be mapped one-to-one into $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @Andreas: True, we can make some statements about what sort of relations the cardinal of the continuum has with $\aleph$'s, but we can't really say "Ah. It's equal to this and that" without "this and that" being somewhat of a trivial statement (e.g. $\Bbb R$ or $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$, or something similar).